# D3 node update - how to select a specific text element among multiple ones?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I got this code for fading in nodes:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
})
    .on("click", collapse);

nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("width", 170)
    .attr("height", 80)
    .attr("x", -85)
    .attr("y", -80)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .style("fill", "#989898")
    .style("stroke", "#65737e");

nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", -80)
    .attr("y", -70)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.title;
});

nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("class", "name")
    .attr("x", -80)
    .attr("y", -70)
    .attr("opacity", 0)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("dy", "1.86em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.firstName + " " + d.lastName;
});
```

And will be updated like this:

```
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});

nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", 170)
    .attr("height", 80)
    .attr("x", -85)
    .attr("y", -80)
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "#989898")
    .style("stroke", "#65737e");

nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", -80)
    .attr("y", -70)
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.title;
});

nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("class", "name")
    .attr("x", -80)
    .attr("y", -70)
    .attr("opacity", 1)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("dy", "1.86em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.firstName + " " + d.lastName;
});
```

My problem is now that I append multiple text elements (title and name) on a single node, but only the last one selected will be shown, as the other ones seem overwritten, since I don't select a specific text element. I tried both saving every element in a variable when appending, as well as selecting them by class, but none of these options did work. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You probably want `.select("text.title")` and `.select("text.name")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple `text` elements that need to be dealt with separately, but you're not distinguishing between them in the selectors. You can do that easily by using the classes that you've assigned to them, i.e. instead of

```
.select("text")
```

you would do

```
.select("text.title")
```

and

```
.select("text.name")
```